# Morphism of varieties defined by the greatest common divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the paper *On the Chow Bunches for Different Projective Embeddings of a Complete Variety*, Hoyt (1966). In this paper the author wants prove that the Chow monoind $\mathcal{C}_p(X)=\bigsqcup_{d\geq 0}\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X)$ given by the disjoint union of Chow varieties $\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X)$ does not depend from the choice of the embedding of the projective variety $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$. In order to do this he needs to prove the following lemma.

[image]
[image]

I don't understand how the condition (ii) defines a closed set and, similarly, the condition (i) defines an open set. Moreover  the author says that $h$ is a morphism, but it's unclear to me his "proof" of this fact.

Any help to understand these arguments is very well appreciated.

PS: I've alredy tried to post the question on MSE without results.

Comment: "I've alredy tried to post the question on MSE without results." You waited just two hours. Two hours! One week is the recommended waiting time. Two hours!! Oh, and the link to the m.se post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781147/morphism-of-varieties-defined-by-the-greatest-common-divisor