# Topological Invariance of Chow Varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a complex projective subvariety. We define the ($p$th) Chow monoid of $X$ as
$$\mathcal{C}_p(X,f)=\bigsqcup_{d\geq 0}\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X,f),$$

where $\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X,f)$ is the Chow variety parametrizing the $p$-dimensional cycles of degree $d\geq 0$ supported in $X$ and, by assumption, $\mathcal{C}_{p,0}(X,f)$ consists only of the cycle with empty support which is the neutal element in the addtion law of the Chow monoid. By puttion on each $\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X,f)$ the analytic topology we endow  $\mathcal{C}_p(X,f)$ with the disjoint union topology. I'm trying to check that the topology on $\mathcal{C}_{p}(X,f)$ does not depend from the choice of the embedding $f\colon X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$, but only from the isomorphism class of $X$. To make precise this statement usually one defines the so called algebraic maps.

**Def.(Continuos Algebraic Map)** A map $F\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ between irreducible projective variety is called *continuos algebraic map* (CAM) if its graph $\Gamma_F\subset X\times Y$ is closed.

The definition above is that given by H.B. Lawson in [Spaces of Algebraic Cycles](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/1993/0002/0001/SDG-1993-0002-0001-a003.pdf).

In the paper [Introduction to Lawson Homology](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~peters/Articles/lawson-intro.pdf) by C. Peters and S. Kosarew, the authors say that $F\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ is a CAM if in addition to the assumptions of the definition above the projection $\Gamma_F\longrightarrow X$ induces a birational morphism (as pointed out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776998/algebraic-maps-and-morphisms?noredirect=1#comment5727506_2776998) this other assumption could be removed, *feel free to share any thoughts*).

If $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint union (possibly not finite)  of irreducible projective varieties, say $X=\bigsqcup_{\alpha} X_\alpha$ and $Y=\sqcup_{\beta}Y_\beta$, than we say that $F$ is a CAM if for any $\alpha$ $F$ induces, by restriction, a continuos algebraic map $F\colon X_\alpha\longrightarrow Y_\beta$. This definition is that given by  C. Peters and S. Kosarew.

In order to check that $\mathcal{C}_{p}(X,f)$ does not depend from $f$ we have to check that if $f'\colon X\subset \mathbb{P}^m$ then there is an algebraic homeomorphism (obvius meaning) from $\mathcal{C}_p(X,f*f')\longrightarrow \mathcal{C}_p(X,f)$, where $f\ast f'$ is the Segre embedding of $X\times X$ into $\mathbb{P}^{nm+n+m}$. It seems that the reference for this is Hoyt's paper [On the Chow Bunches for Different Projective Embeddings of a Complete Variety](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2373192.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). In this paper Hoyt shows that the map $\mathcal{C}_p(X,f*f')\longrightarrow \mathcal{C}_p(X,f)$ we are looking for is that which takes a cycle $(f\ast f')(\xi)$ to $f(\xi)$ which amounts to take the Chow form $F^{(f\ast f')(\xi)}(X_{qi}Y_{qj})=\sum_{n=1}^t A_n(X)M_n(Y)$   to $F^{f(\xi)}(X)=\mathsf{gdc}(A_1(X),\ldots,A_t(X))$.

In the [Lemma 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300211/morphism-of-varieties-defined-by-the-greatest-common-divisor?noredirect=1#comment747224_300211) he proves that if $L$ is some projective space containing $(A_1,\ldots, A_t)$ and $L'$ is the space of forms of degree $d$, then the map the set $U\subset L$ of elements $(A_1,\ldots, A_t)$ having gdc of degree $d$ is locally closed and the map $g\colon U\longrightarrow L'$ taking $(A_1,\ldots,A_t)$ to $\mathsf{gdc}(A_1,\ldots, A_t)$ is a morphism. Then he writes:

[image]

where $Q(f\ast f')$ and $Q(f)$ are irreducible components of $\mathcal{C}_p(X,f\ast f')$ and $\mathcal{C}_p(X,f)$, rispectively.

Homestly I dont' understand how he uses the Lemma to get this conclusion. To be more precise, how can I conclude that the immage of $Q(f\ast f')$ via the gdc-map is contained in $Q(f)$?